Verwendbarkeit von "nichts auf den Rippen haben"
Neben der DWDS-Seite zum Wort Rippe habe ich die Redewendung nichts auf den Rippen haben gefunden, die eine magere Person bezeichnet. Allerdings habe ich kaum Verwendungsbeispiele dafür in Korpora oder bei Google gefunden. Daher vermute ich, dass sie schon veraltet ist. Wie oft begegnet ihr dieser Redewendung? Sollte ich sie noch verwenden, insbesondere wenn ich in Norddeutschland wohne, oder lieber gängigere Alternativen wählen?
Und was haltet ihr von ihrem Gegenstück - zu viel auf den Rippen haben?

Das ist so ein Spruch, den die Oma oder Tante zum Kind sagt, während sie ihm die zweite Portion Schwarzwälder Kirschtorte auf den Teller packt.

Du musst doch was auf die Rippen kriegen, Kind!

Oder auch zu den Eltern:

Der Junge hat ja schon ein bisschen viel auf den Rippen, oder?

Sprachlich veraltet finde ich das nicht, vielleicht im Moment etwas aus der Mode gekommen. Junge Leute würden das im Moment wohl eher weniger benutzen, wenn sie übereinander reden. Bis sie dann selbst die Tanten und Onkel sind ...
Ngram sieht das Maximum der Verwendung in den 1890er-Jahren, und ein Minimum interessanterweise in der Nachkriegszeit ab 1945, als Hunger in Deutschland zuletzt mal wirklich ein Thema war.

Naja, eigentlich ist das "1945-Phänomen" irgendwie keins. Wenn keiner was zu futtern hat, ist das ja auch nicht erwähnenswert.

Die Antwort zur zweiten Teilfrage ergänzend:
zu viel auf den Rippen haben ist mir noch nie begegnet, da würde man vermutlich eine komplett andere Wendung vorziehen, in ähnlichen Kontext etwa:

gut im Futter stehen


Ich kenne zu viel auf den Rippen haben aus meinem Umfeld durchaus als Ausdruck für Übergewicht.
